# How to have Date selector for every button/option clicked in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, radio-button

I am new to Vuejs, I have used 3 buttons which are chart1, chart2 and chart3 respectively. So whenever I click any of the button I want the Date selection to be displayed which is in a radio type. Shown Below:

[image]

What I am trying to do is, I am trying to display the charts, whenever the button is clicked, whichever the button clicked I want to display Date selection.

Here how I tried:

```
<template>
  <div class="Different charts">
    <div class="buttons" >
      <vs-button color="warning" size="small" @click="chartapi(chart1, all)">Chart1</vs-button>
      <vs-button color="warning" size="small" @click="chartapi(chart2, all)" >Chart2</vs-button>
      <vs-button color="warning" size="small" @click="chartapi(chart3, all)">Chart3</vs-button>
    </div>
      <ul class="demo-alignment ">
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="all" color="warning" vs-name="options" vs-value="all" v-model="radios2" >All</vs-radio>
        </li>

        <li>
          <vs-radio id="6mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="6mon" v-model="val1">6mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="3mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="3mon" v-model="val1">3mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="1mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="1mon" v-model="val1">1mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
      </ul>
  <div class="chart-container"> 
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      date: [],
      challenge: [],
      data: [],
      val1: 'all'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.chartapi()
  },
  methods: {
    chartapi (type_name, interval) {
      this.$http.get(`/different/chart/${ type_name  }?interval=${  interval}`)
        .then((r) => {
          this.date = r.data.date
          this.challenge = r.data.challenge
          this.data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
            x: new Date(date * 1000),
            y: this.challenge[index]
          }))

          const ctx = this.$refs.chart.getContext('2d')
          new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: 'Challenge',
                  data: this.data,
                  borderColor: 'black',
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      callback (value) {
                        return `${value}%`
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                      unit: 'month'
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          })
        })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

As you can see my code you can understand that whenever the button is clicked, the respective chart is displayed

And I have used the interval in the method which is used to specify the value of the Date range selection.

My question is how to show the Date range selection for all the options (buttons) and how the interval can be specified in the radio buttons.

For example, if chartapi(chart1, 3mon) then it displays the previous 3 months chart1 data. But what I want is when the button is clicked it should show whole chart data, if the user wants to view any interval he can use the radio buttons which is the Date range selection. So I want to know how to integrate the interval to the radio buttons. Please do help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need to fetch all data when the button clicks and after you will select the radio buttons accordingly and you want to change the data when you change the radio button. so you can change tho code as following,

```
<template>
  <div class="Different charts">
    <div class="buttons" >
      <vs-button color="warning" size="small" @click="handleBtnClick(chart1)">Chart1</vs-button>
      <vs-button color="warning" size="small" @click="handleBtnClick(chart2)" >Chart2</vs-button>
      <vs-button color="warning" size="small" @click="handleBtnClick(chart3)">Chart3</vs-button>
    </div>
      <ul class="demo-alignment ">
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="all" color="warning" vs-name="options" vs-value="all" v-model="val1" >All</vs-radio>
        </li>

        <li>
          <vs-radio id="6mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="6mon" v-model="val1">6mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="3mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="3mon" v-model="val1">3mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="1mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="1mon" v-model="val1">1mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
      </ul>
  <div class="chart-container"> 
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chart from 'chart.js'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      date: [],
      challenge: [],
      data: [],
      val1: 'all',
      type: 'chart1'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.chartapi(type, val1);
  },
  methods: {
      handleBtnClick: (chart) => {
          /* This is a method to use in button click */
          this.type = chart;
          this.val1 = 'all' // Assigning 'all' as initial value for each chart
          this.chartapi(this.type, this.val1);
      },
    chartapi (type_name, interval) {
      this.$http.get(`/different/chart/${ type_name  }?interval=${  interval}`)
        .then((r) => {
          this.date = r.data.date
          this.challenge = r.data.challenge
          this.data = this.date.map((date, index) => ({
            x: new Date(date * 1000),
            y: this.challenge[index]
          }))

          const ctx = this.$refs.chart.getContext('2d')
          new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  label: 'Challenge',
                  data: this.data,
                  borderColor: 'black',
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    ticks: {
                      callback (value) {
                        return `${value}%`
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                      unit: 'month'
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          })
        })
    }
  },
  watch: {
      /* You can write a watcher for listen the changes of the radio button */
      val1:(prevValue, newValue) => {
          /* This method triggers everytime you change the value of val1 */
          this.chartapi(this.type, newValue);
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

The changes I do was,

1. Add separate data filed/variable to assign the type of the chart
2. create a separate method to trigger the buttons that change the `type` variable accordingly and change the `val1` back to all.
3. Create watcher to watch the `val1` and if `val1` changes loading the chart respectively.

**Update**

Since you are unclear about how watcher works, we can create watchers in vue as a special kind of function which will trigger when the relevant data field is updated.

first, we bind our radio buttons to the `val1` data field as follows.

```
<ul class="demo-alignment ">
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="all" color="warning" vs-name="options" vs-value="all" v-model="val1" >All</vs-radio>
        </li>

        <li>
          <vs-radio id="6mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="6mon" v-model="val1">6mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="3mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="3mon" v-model="val1">3mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
        <li>
          <vs-radio id="1mon" color="warning"  vs-name="options" vs-value="1mon" v-model="val1">1mon</vs-radio>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

as you can see all the radio buttons are `v-bind` with `val1` so the value of val1 changes according to the selected radio button. (all, 6mon, 3mon, 1mon).

next, we create weather to the `val1` as the following code.

```
watch: {
      /* You can write a watcher for listen the changes of the radio button */
      val1: (prevValue, newValue) => {
          /* This method triggers everytime you change the value of val1 */
          this.chartapi(this.type, newValue);
      }
  }
```

we create watcher with the same name as the data field and it triggers each time the `val1` changes, (that mean it triggers when you change the radio button). then inside that watcher when the value changes we call `chartapi` with the new value of `val1` as a second parameter. which makes the chart to load again according to the selected month.

Comment: Thank you so much for the buttons part, but what exactly i wanted is, i have 3 buttons, so whenever i click any of the button, initially entire chart i.e with 'all' interval should be displayed, then if user wishes to change the interval of the chart, he can do it by changing the radio buttons, so now i want know how to integrate the chart interval such as '6mon' '3mon' & '1mon' to radio buttons and most importantly the radio buttons must be shown for any chart buttons clicked. Please do help me with this.

Comment: @app_er I think you have the answer as I understand if you pass all as a second parameter of the chart API method it retrieves the entire chart. so in the method `handleBtnClick` every time `val1` changes to `all` so and pass it to the second parameter. So each time when you click the button you fetch all the data and reset radio button to all.  for your second need, there is the watcher on the `val1` which triggers each and every time you change your radio button. So that scenario also addressed as I think. you have to change the all radio also to connect the same v-model as my changed code.

Comment: Hello @Vikum Dheemantha, i just tried your answer and it is working absolutely fine, but when i have selected chart1, i am able to see the chart1 with "all" interval and with the 'all' radio button checked , and as of now everything is fine, but if the user wishes to change the radio button the chart1 has to change that means initially it will be displayed with "all" interval so only like "all" radio button will be checked, If user changes the radio button like "6m" is checked, then the interval of chart1 must change from "all"  to " "6m" interval. I hope you understood, please help me.

Comment: Objective: Suppose chart1 is clicked, it should display chart with 'all' interval, so "all" is checked. If the radio button is changed to "6m" the date range of chart1 must change and must display chart1 with "6m" interval and so on respectively. But initially it should display the "all" interval when clicked any chart. So, i want @click in every radio buttons, which should change the respective interval same as name of the respective chart clicked. Please do help me with this.

Comment: @app_er yes I got the idea. you can add @click to the radio buttons and achieve the same goal but that method will be complex. But that kind of situations vue.js `watchers` comes handy. with that, you can watch the data field and make it to do something when the data field changes. if you bind date correctly with the radio buttons then that `watcher` method I created should call chart data accordingly. check https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers for more details about the vue watchers.

Comment: Hello Vikum, can you please show me with my code at least for 6m radio button, because i tried using the events but that dint workout properly.

Comment: @app_er I update the answer by explaining how to use watchers.

Comment: Thank you @Vikum, can you please show me one last example , so whenever i click on the 6m radio button the interval of the chart must change from all to 6m

Comment: @app_er inside the watcher function, you can do anything and that will execute when you change the radio buttons. in this case, you can call the chartapi again with the month selection as an interval, as I mentioned above answer. if it did not working means you have to check your chart API and find out what kind of value should pass to the interval.

Comment: Hello @Vikum Dheemantha, i tried click function for the radio button but nothing is working. So please help me, currently when i load my page the chart1 is displayed and 'all' radio btn is checked that indicates chart1 is showing interval-'all'. Now, suppose i change the radio button to 6m, i want the interval also to change to '6', you can see my code for buttons i have given @click(chartapi('chart1', 'all')), here i have specified the intervall as 'all' , but on clicking the radio btns i want that interval to change and display respective chart.

Comment: Similarly, if user click the chart2 button then chart2 must be displayed with 'all' radio btn checked, then if user wants to view different interval of chart2 then, he can change the radio btns, if he clicks 6m then chart2 interval=6 should be displayed, if he clicks 3m then chart2 with interval=3 must be displayed. But initially when page is loaded chart1 with interval =all should be loaded and 'all' radio btn must be checked. Please do help me with at least one example, because i need to undersatand how it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226862/discussion-between-vikum-dheemantha-and-app-er).